# Python Script can be executed manually but not by using Crontab

Tags: python, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I also used shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python`

My script is executable also 
I am currently using pattern

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/python3.5m file_name.py
```

other pattern:

```
dir_path && usr/local/bin/python3.5m dir_path/file_name.py
```

Comment: how you are sure that script is not running it runs in daemon mode

Comment: Are you on windows and you use Ubuntu on it?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04 only.